# Как подсчитать строки в файле из терминала в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Какая команда наиболее проста и удобна?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Команда `wc` выводит количество переводов строк, слов и байтов в текстовом файле.
Например.

```
echo "Первая сторока" > текст
echo "Вторая сторока" >> текст
wc -l текст
2 текст
```